# yum update with shared cache

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

We've got a big batch of RHEL6 machines that are due for patching, and for some reason the process here does not involve a local repo. I'm new here, I've asked why, ["it just didn't work"] and I don't have enough time to make it work before the window that's already scheduled.

So the usual method is to install `yum-downloadonly` and run `yum update --downloadonly --downloaddir=/mnt/cifs_share` and then `yum update /mnt/cifs_share/*.rpm` which just does not look right to me since not all of these machines have the same set of installed packages.

The method I tried today was mounting the share to `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/rhel-x86_64-server-6/packages/` which *worked*, but then yum automatically deleted everything  once it finished.

I've looked over the `yum` man page, but I don't see any flag I can feed it to stop it from deleting everything, nor a flag like up2date's `--tmpdir=/mnt/cifs_share`.

Can anyone out there help me kludge this together until I can get a local repository working?

Comment: Can you just bring up a caching proxy server (squid?) quickly, and point yum at the proxy server?  You will need to tweak it so it keeps the large package files, but it should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
keepcache=1
```

This will cause `yum` to leave the downloaded packages in place after installation.